# SQL- Find the students who are missing their grades in database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three tables in my database. the first one is students which has student_id as primary key. the second one is courses table which has course_id as primary key and at last I have a grades table which has id_student and id_course as foreign keys, and a grade field. I want to the get details of students, who are missing their grades in grades table.
I've searched on stack overflow but could not find the exact answer i am looking for. and what i have tried so far is this following query:

```
select st.student_id,
       st.lname,
       st.fname,
       cs.course_id,
       g.grade 
from students st 
join grades g 
   on g.id_student = st.student_id 
join courses cs 
   on cs.course_id = g.id_course 
where g.grade is null
```

If I try this same query without where condition i get 39 rows but i should get 40 because in my database there is one student who is missing grades in course_id 20.
** the missing thing is student_id, where course_id is 20 and grade doesnt exist for it.**

[image: this is my students table]

[image: this is courses table]
[image]

Comment: Change your JOINS to LEFT OUTER JOIN

Comment: I guess its join clause, your 40th student could be missing a record in one of the tables. If you do not specify `join`' by default is an inner join, try using `left join`. However, we will need some sample data and sample output to verify the exact reason. It was a good attempt on your end

Comment: @AntDC `select st.student_id,st.lname,st.fname,cs.course_id,g.grade from students st LEFT OUTER join grades g on g.id_student = st.student_id LEFT OUTER join courses cs on cs.course_id = g.id_course where g.grade is null` I have tried this but still no luck

Comment: There is NO grade row for the student in question so the WHERE clause is excluding him - Have modified my answer to include a possible solution.

Comment: Please provide sample data as well as desired results.  How do you know which students should be taking which courses?

Comment: It is not clear to me if just the grade column is missing a value or the row is simply not there.
IMO - The query for all grades shoulkd be driven off of the grades table and missing grades done with another  NOT EXISTS query

Comment: How can a student even enroll in a course if the association between student and course is via grade? Either your schema is a mess or you left out important information?

Comment: @SMor this is just a college excercise. In here students are supposed to take every course

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the `join` on `grades` requires *two* keys.  If I assume that students should be taking all courses, then this would look like:

```
select st.student_id, st.lname, st.fname, cs.course_id,
       g.grade 
from students st cross join
     courses c left join
     grades g 
     on g.id_student = st.student_id and
        g.id_course = c.course_id
where g.grade is null;
```

The `CROSS JOIN` generates all combinations of students and courses.  The `LEFT JOIN`/`WHERE` filters out the ones with missing grades.

Answer (score 0):

Because you use JOIN you are only getting the rows that exist in all 3 tables.

If you change the JOINS to LEFT OUTER JOIN you will see NULLS for the student without a grade.

See https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp
and many other links on the web

```
SELECT * FROM
(
select st.student_id,st.lname,st.fname,cs.course_id,g.grade 
from students st 
LEFT OUTER join grades g on g.id_student = st.student_id 
LEFT OUTER join courses cs on cs.course_id = g.id_course 
)SUB_Q WHERE SUB_Q.grade IS NULL
```

The inner query should return all students and the ones without a grade should have a grade of null in that.  So the WHERE clause of the outer query should filter down to just those.

Comment: I have updated my question, you can check if anything helps. this query still doesnt works.

Comment: so there is definately no row in grade with student_Id = 4 and course_Id = 20?
or is there a row that doesn't have the grade set?

Answer (score 0):

The join function for the grades table is only looking for results that match both the grades table and students table. Try a full outer join here to include all fields regardless of if they match on both tables. See code below:

```
SELECT 
st.student_id, st.lname, st.fname, cs.course_id, g.grade

FROM students st

FULL OUTER JOIN grades g
ON g.id_student = st.student_id

FULL OUTER JOIN courses cs
ON cs.course_ID = g.id_course

WHERE g.grade IS NULL
```